Execute a SOQL or Anonymous apex code every minute
I have a requirement where I need to execute a SOQL on Contact object every minute from 4 am to 5 am and capture the results for every execution. I don't want to create a batch apex and schedule it to execute every minute since this is only for troubleshooting a production issue.
Is there a way to execute the SOQL automatically from 4 am to 5 am? Or is there a way to execute this piece of apex code from "Execute Anonymous" windows automatically from 4 am to 5 am?
Thanks in advance.
Adding Additional Info:
We have one particular contact that gets deactivated every day morning between 4 to 5 even we activate it every day. We have several batch jobs running from midnight to 6 AM. So, I just want to execute a SOQL query or apex code to query the status of the contact after every minute and figure out which batch job is flipping the status of the contact from Active to Inactive.

What do you want to achieve by running a SOQL every minute?

Right now, this is an XY Problem. What is the bigger picture here? What does running this query (and doing stuff with the results) every minute help you accomplish?

Reading this again, the 4-5 AM part makes me think that this may be some improper datetime handling. Check for code that is trying to take a Date and shove it into a Datetime. If you find anything like that, changing to something like Datetime myDT = Datetime.newInstance(Date.today(), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)); may be all you need to resolve the issue.

Updated the original post with more info.

could you not simply set up a trace for the running user(s) and for that time range, then look at the LastModifiedDate to narrow it down a bit?

Is there an option of enabling history tracking on that active field and see who has modified it. Also if all your batch jobs are running with different user, this could be easily caught from history tracking.

Not sure if it can help more than writing a schedulable batch, but you can try out a free app from Salesforce Labs that offer running the anonymous apex by schedule
Schedul-o-matic 9000

This turned out to be a genuine X-Y problem.
Your real question is: Which batch job changes the status of a Contact?
The obvious solution is to use Field Tracking History, but I guess you already knew that and I guess you have already reached the limit of 20 fields.
The next thing you can do: use Feed Tracking. This gives you an additional 20 fields allowing you to track changes in field values. These changes can be seen in the Chatter tab of the Contact.

The field history tracking is enabled for this status field, but we have more than 50 jobs running during the batch cycle and all jobs run with the same service account and the updates are not directly happening in Salesforce code. The actual update is made on the SQL Server side and it is pushed to Salesforce using a third party product. So, it makes it little hard to track the job cycles and troubleshoot from Salesforce end.
